# Using indexededDb in phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, indexeddb

I want to build a offline application  using phonegap and for that I need a localdatabase. I have an index.js file that loads my application and in there i have a global variable.

```
var db;
```

I have a controller that when the users logs in it save the database info in an indexeddb database the user can use it offline.

```
 //controller call
 Database.create(res.data.categories);

function Database() {

return {
    create: function (categoryDocs) {
        var request = indexedDB.open("kaldoa", 1);

        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            db = event.target.result;
            console.log("DB loaded successfully");
        };

        request.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log(event)
        };

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            db = event.target.result;
            console.log("DB initiliazed / created");

            //create collections
            db.createObjectStore("categories", {autoIncrement: true});

            //create documents
            var transaction = event.target.transaction;
            var categories = transaction.objectStore("categories");

            //add array objects to document
            categories.add(categoryDocs);

        };

    }
}

}
```

When i check in the chrome inspector the dbs have being created and everything is good.

Now i want to display the data that was stored named categories.

I do that in another controller that handles categories.

```
function categoryCtrl($scope, Category){

Category.browse().onsuccess = function (e) {
    $scope.categories = e.target.result.value;
};
```

}

The problem im having is that the data works in chrome but it doesn't work in phonegap. In phonegap i get this console.error

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'db.transaction')
```

This console error is associated with the services that fetch the categories data

```
function Category() {

return {
    browse: function () {
        return db.transaction(["categories"], "readonly").objectStore("categories").openCursor()
    }
}
}
```

I have breaking my head all day trying to figure out why it works in chrome but not in phonegap. I know is ios 10 released on september 29, 2016 apple added support for both safari and webview.

[indexeddb ios support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a global db variable like this. It is not guaranteed to be defined and open at the time you access it. This is because of how async code works.